# params in javascript node url

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on nodejs api where I need to pass username and password in post request url at params with axios package, 
for example:
http://someUrl:5000/oauth/token?client_id=clusterName&username=johndoe&password=password

I have an issue when i'm passing password with # at the beggining, 
what i'm getting is: http://someUrl:5000/oauth/token?client_id=clusterName&username=johndoe&password=

the url sliced after the # character , when i'm passing # in middle of the password all works fine, 
thanks for your help

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Use the request body to pass credentials, doing so over a query string like this is completely insecure and can be read in the clear even over TLS.

Comment: But to answer your question, as the answer says the part after the `#` is a fragment and is not parsed as party of the query string parameters.  The fragment is typically used for hyperlink anchors and routing in SPA applications.

Answer (score 0):

String after hash is different part of url and it's called **fragment**. So it cannot be part of query params. See this response: [What are fragment URLs and why to use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997420/what-are-fragment-urls-and-why-to-use-them)

In your case it's better to use **payload** to send user's credentials instead of query parameters.