# How to use string variable that have special character "#" in select query statement mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

include('dbLink2.php');


$quizqr = $_GET['quizQR'];
$recordsID1 = $_GET['recordsID1'];
$recordsID2 = $_GET['recordsID2'];

$m_array1=array();
$m_array=array();
    
    $sql = "SELECT quizQR, recordsID FROM `registertestactivity` WHERE (quizQR = '$quizqr' OR recordsID = '$recordsID1' OR recordsID = '$recordsID2') LIMIT 1";
    $result = @mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die();
    
    if (@mysqli_affected_rows($link) > 0) {
    
        while($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $m_array[]=$row;
        }

    } else {
        
        $m_array1 += ["quizQR" => "NoRecords"];
        $m_array1 += ["recordsID" => "NoRecords"];
                
        $m_array[0] = $m_array1;
        
    }   
        
    echo json_encode($m_array);

@mysqli_free_result($result);
@mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Can someone help me out, i have tried the mysqli_real_escape_string and it still doesnt work :(

The $quizqr value has a '#' character in the string and this is the error msg that pops when the ajax call this php:
[image: click to see error message image]

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Remove every single `@` in your code. You're suppressing messages which might be valuable to you.

Comment: You should [never use `die()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1011527) and use `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` with your database connection code to throw errors for all of your queries when they occur.

Comment: Along with the above, `#` is a URL fragment.  Everything after that isn't sent to the server.

Comment: The URL you're using to access this script doesn't have the necessary variables in the query string of the URL. Can you share the URL?

Comment: the db connection ? or the ajax i call to this php?

Comment: The AJAX connection.

Comment: @JayBlanchard  `url: web_address + "backend/get_regTestCheck.php?quizQR=" + quiz_qr + "&recordsID1=" + recordID1 + "&recordsID2=" + recordID2`

Comment: @JayBlanchard so an example of data would be `url: web_address + "backend/get_regTestCheck.php?quizQR=C-Q01/00000054#/065-10K/5XP-0521 GG0E&recordsID1=records_001&recordsID2=records_002`

Comment: If you `print_r($_GET);` at the top of the page, what do you get?

Comment: @JayBlanchard  `Array ( [quizQR] => C-Q01/00000054 )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have a `#` in the URL you're dealing with a [URL Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997420/what-are-fragment-urls-and-why-to-use-them) which means that everything past the `#` is not available in the query string. PHP offers a flag, `PHP_URL_FRAGMENT` for its [`parse_url()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function which can help you get what you need from the string.

Here is one [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d41ea52658fb734d33c612f814614aaf4658b827) using the URL you provided:

```
$fragment = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);
echo $fragment;
$fragmentSection = explode('&', $fragment);
print_r($fragmentSection);

foreach($fragmentSection AS $section) {
    if(0 != strpos($section, '=')) {
        $sectionParts = explode('=', $section);
        $queryParts[$sectionParts[0]] = $sectionParts[1];
    }
}
print_r($queryParts);
```

This ultimately returns two array members which could then be used in your query:

```
Array
(
    [recordsID1] => records_001
    [recordsID2] => records_002
)
```

The best thing to do would be to write a function to which you pass the URL to return the elements you need.

**Keep in mind** that this is not fool-proof. If the URL is in a different format then what I have done here will have to be modified to work as you would like it to.

**Additionally** you have been given some warnings and guidance in the comments you should follow to keep your code safe and efficient, so I will not repeat them here.

Comment: Thank you for your help! will take note of the guidance to keep the codes safe!