# how to resolve connection issue with URL when using `open` function

Tags: r, url, curl, httr, urlconnection

In order to find some features that I need, I want to establish a connection to a website using `open(mycon, "r")`. To do this, I used the code below which is provided by @Dunois:

```
myx <- httr::HEAD(example)$url
mycon <- url(myx)
open(mycon, "r")
```

where `example` is a link to a website. This code works perfectly for all websites; however, in some unique cases like `"https://www.pixilink.com/140079#mode=tour"` or `"https://www.pixilink.com/141152#mode=0"` it doesn't work. These websites exist and I check them in my browser and I am not sure why the connection cannot be established. The error message I get is:

`Error in open.connection(mycon, "r") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message: In open.connection(mycon, "r") : cannot open URL 'https://www.pixilink.com/140079#mode=tour': HTTP status was '400 Bad Request'`

I appreciate it if you can shed light on this and clarify why I get this error message?

Comment: I'm not getting that error on Linux using R 3.6.3. On the other hand I'm not sure what I should be doing with that fact. R is not a browser.

Comment: @IRTFM, of course, R is not a browser. The reason I need this is to open the website and then using `readLines`, `httr:HEAD` and other functions to determine if the website includes video or photo, that's why it's important for me to make sure I have the right connection with the website and then do any post-processing that is required

Comment: @IRTFM , and I must say I am surprised that you don't get this error on Linux. kind of confusing...

Comment: @Roozbeh_you Remove those URL fragments after the hash mark `#`. Then your connection should work.

Comment: @ekoam, yes this works, but then I have to search for all these `#` and remove them in my dataset, right? is there any reason that it's not working with `#`? Alos, this just an example, what if that the connection fails to be opened in other cases? My understanding was that `open` will open the connection if it's valid but it seems that there are some cases like this that it can't handle it

Comment: I do think those fragments make your connection not work. URL fragments are linked to internal sections on the web page specified by the main URL. When you provide a URL with fragments, your browser redirects you to the main webpage automatically. However, R's `open` function doesn't do that redirection, so I think that's why you cannot "open" the web page. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30997598/10802499) for detailed explanations about URL fragments. It's not hard to remove those fragments, though. Check the `fragment` function from the `urltools` package. @Roozbeh_you