# MVC Core. RedirectToAction(action, controller, routeValues, fragment). Access fragment parameter value in target Action

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm submitting:

```
/abc/def/xyz
```

into:

```
public IActionResult ExtractFragment(string param1, string param2, string wantedFragment)
```

So I'm redirecting into:

```
public IActionResult MyAction(string param1, string param2)
```

Via:

```
return RedirectToAction("MyAction", "MyController", new ( param1 = param1, param2 = param2), wantedFragment);
```

And the resulting URL is:

```
/abc/def#xyz
```

**Question:**

How can I access the value of `wantedFragment` in MyAction?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are fragment URLs and why to use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997420/what-are-fragment-urls-and-why-to-use-them) Fragments are not sent to the server at all in HTTP.

Comment: It looks like you don't fully understand fragments on the URL. You can generate an URL with fragment with one of `RedirectToAction()` overrides that takes the fragment as parameter. But you can't get the fragment from the URL back to controller action. URL fragments only exit in your browser. They don't get sent in HTTP messages so your server would never get them.

Comment: @juunas I'm not submitting a fragment from the browser. I'm redirecting within the framework... The resulting URL from MyAction has the fragment... I need the value to build up the view model...

Comment: You are returning a redirect. That means the browser requests that URL. The fragment is not sent. You can use for example TempData or query string to pass the value instead.

Comment: @juunas I appreciate the clarification - thank you. TempData is the solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Four solutions:

1.pass wantedFragment in a querystring,and your resulting url will be `/abc/def?wantedFragment=xyz`

demo:

```
[Route("/{param1}/{param2}/{wantedFragment}")]
        public IActionResult ExtractFragment(string param1, string param2, string wantedFragment)
        
        {
            return RedirectToAction("MyAction", "My", new { param1 = param1, param2 = param2, wantedFragment = wantedFragment });
        }
        [Route("/{param1}/{param2}")]
        public IActionResult MyAction(string param1, string param2,string wantedFragment) {
            return Ok();
        }
```

result:
[image]

2.TempData,and your resulting url will be `/abc/def`：

demo:

```
[Route("/{param1}/{param2}/{wantedFragment}")]
        public IActionResult ExtractFragment(string param1, string param2, string wantedFragment)
        {
            TempData["wantedFragment"] = wantedFragment;
            return RedirectToAction("MyAction", "My", new { param1 = param1, param2 = param2});
        }
        [Route("/{param1}/{param2}")]
        public IActionResult MyAction(string param1, string param2) {
            var wantedFragment = TempData["wantedFragment"];
            return Ok();
        }
```

result:
[image]

3.Session,and your resulting url will be `/abc/def`
demo:

```
[Route("/{param1}/{param2}/{wantedFragment}")]
        public IActionResult ExtractFragment(string param1, string param2, string wantedFragment)
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("wantedFragment", wantedFragment);
            return RedirectToAction("MyAction", "My", new { param1 = param1, param2 = param2});
        }
        [Route("/{param1}/{param2}")]
        public IActionResult MyAction(string param1, string param2) {
            var wantedFragment = HttpContext.Session.GetString("wantedFragment");
            return Ok();
        }
```

Startup:

ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
```

Configure:

```
app.UseSession();
```

result:
[image]

4.Except these,you can also try to use Cookie,and your resulting url will be `/abc/def`

Comment: 2. Is the simplest solution. It's good to see the possible alternatives in action. @Yiyi You Thanks.