# Nginx redirect path to a new structure not working with "#"

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to create the following rewrite in nginx:

```
https://my-domain/app/kibana#/discover?<some-get-params>
```

to

```
https://new-domain/app/discover#/?<some-get-params>
```

I'm struggling I think because of the "#" character.
I am able to redirect to the destination, but always without the params.

My last attempt was as follows:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/app/kibana#/discover(.*)$ https://my-new-domain.com/app/discover#/$1 redirect;
}
```

What happens with this one is a 404.

If instead I do something like:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/app/kibana(.*)$ https://my-new-domain.com/app/discover#/$args redirect;
}
```

I get redirected to the right destination but without any args: https://my-new-domain.com/app/discover#/
Same thing if instead of $args I use $1 instead

Comment: The `#` is the beginning of the [URL fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997420/what-are-fragment-urls-and-why-to-use-them) which is never sent to Nginx. So Nginx cannot help you here.

Comment: -.- thanks! I'll have to find a workaround for that then.